# Running a Macro on single or range of columns

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

I believe this should be an easy one for you vets out there...

I have the following Macro that will change a "data format of any kind" to m/d/yyyy format, but with the "ActiveCell.Column" portion, I have to select each column 1 at a time. Wondering if there's a way to have it work on individual columns or a range of columns selected... My first thought was to simply change "ActiveCell.Column" to "ActiveCell.Column**s**", but this didn't work...
VBA code below:

```
Sub change_2_short_dt()

    a = ActiveCell.Column
    Columns(a).Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Reference (Select) Columns

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub change_2_short_dt()

    Dim rg As Range
    
    ' Validate the selection.
    If Not TypeOf Selection Is Range Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    Else
        ' Reference the range ('rg'). 
        With Selection

            ' Entire worksheet columns.
            Set rg = .EntireColumn

            ' Worksheet used range columns (no columns outside it).
            'Set rg = Intersect(.EntireColumn, .Worksheet.UsedRange)

            ' Columns starting in the same row and of same size
            ' as the columns of the worksheet used range.
            'Set rg = Intersect(.EntireColumn, .Worksheet.UsedRange.EntireRow)

        End With
    
    End If
    
    ' Test with 'Select' to see what is selected (referrenced).
    rg.Select
    MsgBox "Selection Address " & rg.Address(0, 0), vbInformation
    ' When done testing, use the following instead:

    ' Apply number format.        
    'rg.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    'MsgBox "Selection Address: " & rg.Address(0, 0) & vbLf _
        & "Selection Number Format: " & rg.NumberFormat, vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: with the above, when i selected 2 columns side-by-side, it just popped a message mentioning which columns were selected without changing the date format to "short date".. :(

Comment: That's the testing mode. I wouldn't want you to damage any of your data. It shows what would be formatted. When you're satisfied with what is selected, out-comment the `rg.Select` line and the `MsgBox` line right below it and uncomment the last two lines to apply the number format. BTW you can select any cells on the worksheet, they don't have to be adjacent to each other.

Answer (score 2):

Normally one would avoid using `Select`, e.g.

```
Columns(1).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy" ' single column
Columns("A").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyy" ' can also use column letter
Columns("A:E").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy" ' multiple columns
```

If you want to rely on the `Selection`:

```
Selection.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyy"
```

Comment: This time you beat me by seconds